# How do you deal with the Same-Origin-Policy for cookies in Safari Browser?

Tags: cookies, safari, cross-domain

I just want to place a Cookie on `example.com`. On this website I have a code like this: `<script src="http://other-website.com/cookie.js"></script>`

`other-website.com/cookie.js` is just some simple JavaScipt code to set a cookie. But in Safari it's not working because of the `Same-Origin-Policy`.

Of course this is just an example my issue is a little bit more complex. I don't want to include an external .js file just to set a cookie ;)

Comment: Clarification: Are you writing the `script` tag which is sourcing the external `js` on a webpage that is hosted on `example.com`?

Comment: Yes the I am writing the script tag on example.com myself.

Answer (score 0):

It's because Same Origin Policy, just as you figured out.
According to the policy, a script from another domain (such as yours), cannot access the cookies of the origin website.

The limitation is present in order to prevent data stealing such as cookie stealing, in this case.

You'll have to put the script under the same domain.